# Adding scheduling assistant shortcut to Outlook

Tags: outlook, ms-office, outlook-addin

I have been looking for a solution to launch scheduling assistant without actually first creating a meeting/appointment.

I saw it somewhere that they had an icon on the first page itself (somewhere near "File"). A person can launch scheduling assistant on single click and it had list of all employees.
It was a long time ago and I can't really recall the exact details. May be anyone of you have used it or using it right now and can help me with how to configure it.

I have searched a lot (a lot actually!) but have had no luck unfortunately.

Tia!

Answer (score 1):

The Scheduling Assistant can only be displayed in a Meeting Appointment window.  You can however add the Ribbon command of the same name to a custom Ribbon or the Quick Access Toolbar, if you don't like the placement of the existing Scheduling Assistant button.